Get value of textbox in current scope of Crosstab in Telerik Reporting
I have a crosstab report with some frustrating client constraints requiring me to put in occasional monthly summaries for reports that might cross over multiple months. To do this in SQL reporting I used the ReportItems collection to reference a textbox in a different column group.
Does Telerik have a way to do this -- to reference a textbox in the same row but different column group?
